# create style element, define some classes and add class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is there any better way?

```
$("< style >").attr("type","text/css").prependTo("head").append(".bor {border:2px dotted red} .gto {padding:10px; font-size:medium}");

$("input:text").addClass("bor gto").val("your text");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adatepe/aLmc2/

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it this way as opposed to having a CSS file already built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by any chance you need to do this way why not do it the simple way then?

```
$("<style type='text/css'>.bor {border:2px dotted red}" + 
  " .gto {padding:10px; font-size:medium}</style>").prependTo("head");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could [set the CSS directly](http://api.jquery.com/css) rather than trying to build CSS classes at runtime:

```
$('input:text').css({
    border: '2px dotted red',
    padding: '10px',
    fontSize: 'medium'
}).val('your text');
```